# copying char* from method scope

Tags: c++, string, scope

I am trying to figure out a safe way of getting char* strings to exist outside of the methods the original variable was declared in.

For example:

```
void SomeFunc(someclass* c)
{
    char* stringA = "hello";
    c->stringB = stringA;
}
```

This is all fine but when the function returns, the memory that stringA was stored in is destroyed and stringB points to some random mess of memory now.

What is a safe way to manage keeping a copy of the string from stringA without having it be destroyed in stringB? Or should I just allocate new memory and delete it later?

Comment: "the memory that stringA was stored in is destroyed and stringB points to some random mess of memory now." - no, that is incorrect. `"hello"` has static storage duration and `stringB` successfully points to it even after this function returns.  If your program seems to be misbehaving, the error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with `char`, the simplest and best way to do this is to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)! `std::string` will handle copying the local object and allow you to use it outside the function:

```
std::string CreateWord()
{
    return "hello";
}

int main()
{
    const auto word = CreateWord(); // create the word
    std::cout << word << std::endl; // print the word to console
}
```

Because `std::string` is a handy wrapper container for `char`, it makes more sense to use it in your example; however, if you were using some kind of user-defined object, you would need to allocate memory on the heap rather than on the stack. You can/should use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) rather than a raw pointer for this purpose: `std::unique_ptr` allows you to safely allocate and transfer ownership of memory, and makes more sense readability-wise:

```
std::unique_ptr<UserObject> CreateObj()
{
    return std::make_unique<UserObject>();
}

int main()
{
    auto obj = CreateObj();
    // Use UserObject...
}
```

`CreateObj()` will allocate the memory to store the word in, then return a pointer to that memory.

Comment: Thank you, I will format my code to use those things.

Comment: `"hello"` is not "on the stack"

Comment: @M.M yeah my initial thoughts were quite muddled :\ I took a moment to re-organise them to make more sense

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "c++ std::string " ,Above code will work fine as long as c->stringB is a std::string itself .Reason is std::string internally makes copy of the string and it will do the task of new allocation for you .

```
class someclass{
public:
std::string stringB ;
};
void SomeFunc(someclass* c)
{
    char* stringA = "hello";
    c->stringB = stringA;
}
```

Above code will work fine .

If , for reason you don't want to use "std::string" , you need to do the same work i.e. allocating a new memory , passing local char string to it and returning it .Recommendation would still be with std::string .

Comment: The original code works just fine, even if `c->stringB` has type `const char*`. There is no inherent need to copy the **static** string `"hello"` anywhere. Of course, that could be an artifact of simplifying for the question; certainly, if the text goes into a local variable it needs to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

just allocate the memory for stringB and copy the value of stringA to stringB's area. remeber to release the memory in the someclass's destructor。